# Convert WSDL to XML Tool?

Tags: xml, wsdl

Does anyone know of a tool / program to convert a WSDL to XML?

Basically I just want an empty XML template. I can populate the nodes with data after I get the template.

Comment: Can you explain further what you want to do?  Technically WSDL is XML (see [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extract XML request/response [templates from the WSDL using SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/working-with-messages.html).

SoapUI is actually useful at a lot of things like web service mocking, unit testing etc. It is a great tool.

Here is what it generates for an operation in one of their examples at: http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:ConversionRate>
         <web:FromCurrency>?</web:FromCurrency>
         <web:ToCurrency>?</web:ToCurrency>
      </web:ConversionRate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:ConversionRateResponse>
         <web:ConversionRateResult>?</web:ConversionRateResult>
      </web:ConversionRateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: SoapUI is really good. It helped me to extract the request from a WSDL file too.